# Scala Seq's filterNot implementation doesn't accept another List as function input parameter

Tags: scala

I'm working with collections and found this a bit weird:

```
  val a = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  a.filterNot(Seq(1, 2, 3))

  //=> expected output: List(4, 5, 6)
  //=> actual: compiler error

<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: Boolean
       a.filterNot(List(1, 2, 3))
```

But, this version works:

```
  val a = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  a.filterNot(Set(1, 2, 3))

  //=> expected output: List(4, 5, 6)
  //=> actual: List(4, 5, 6)
```

I wonder why this happens. I read both Seq and Set definitions but found any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the `apply()` method for `Seq` and `Set` collections. Look at the definition of `filterNot()`:

```
def filterNot(p: (A) ⇒ Boolean): Seq[A]
```

It takes a function that, when fed an element, returns a Boolean. `Set` does that. `Seq` does not.

```
Set(2,3,6).apply(0)  //res0: Boolean = false
Seq(2,3,6).apply(0)  //res1: Int = 2
```

So when you invoke `a.filterNot(Set(1, 2, 3))`, the `Set` passed in to the `filterNot` is applied to each of the elements from the Seq, `a`, which will result in `true` or `false`, which is what the `filterNot()` requires.

Answer (score 3):

An easily overlooked fact is that a [`Set[A]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/Set.html) extends `A => Boolean`. In other words, a `Set` *is* a predicate (one that checks for membership). This is why you can pass a `Set` to `filterNot`.